# Eclipse: Separate out projects based on perspective

Tags: java, python, c++, eclipse, pydev

So currently I have eclipse running with Pydev, C++ and Java support. When i want to program the project that I want, I switch perspective and use the needed one.

Works great, but one issue I currently have is how do i separate out the projects based on perspective. Lets say i click on C++ perspective, how do I make sure I only get the c++ projects?

Currently when ever i change the perspective I still see the projects from other perspective. Is there any way I can have this in Eclipse?

Comment: Open the top menu "Window->Show View". There should be a view window for each type of project. Open the view for C/C++ projects in the C/C++ perspective and it will only list C/C++ files in the project explorer window to the left. Do the same for the other perspectives. This should all be set up by default though.